# Sign XML document in web browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-signature

I would like to sign XML document(XMLDSig) that contains a sensitive data in the web browser with a client certificate using just JavaScript.

I've done my research and found out, that in 2014-2015 it wasn't possible to sign a document in JS with a client certificate. There were three possibilities back then:

1. Java applet
2. ActiveX component
3. web browser plugin (NPAPI, ...)

Are there any new possibilities nowadays? We're in 2018 and vast majority of resources, I was able to find, are 3-4 years old. So I'm really curious if there is a cross platform and cross browser solution based purely on Javascript and some industry standard.

Comment: Where will the client certificate be stored?

Comment: Certificate should be stored in a system or in the web browser keystore. It's not possible to store encrypted certificate on a disc.

Comment: If you store the certificate in the browser using the new WebCryptographyApi you will  will be able to make digital signatures using only javascript. But you can't use the system keystore (e.g Windows Keystore)

Comment: Can you give me a hint about how it works? I tried to dig some information and found only mentions about "WebCrypto Key Discovery". But it looks it hasn't been implemented in browsers yet.

Comment: Do not take into account the "key discovery API". It is only a definition of the services needed to access the repositories of system certificates. It is not implemented. You can find the webcrypto specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/). It allows to generate or import keys using a native api. It is a low-level api: You can use cryptographic algorithms, but you can't perform advanced operations such as XML signatures or import PKCS#12 files

Answer (score 0):

We have created [a XMLDSIG api](http://xadesjs.com) that you can use from the browser to create XMLDSIG signatures in the browser.

Do signatures you will need a digital certificate, we use what we call a [Browser Bound certificate](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=503) to do this normally. In essence, we create a certificate using Web Crypto and then sign with that.

If you need to use a certificate that was created outside of the browser we have created a package we call [FortifyApp](https://fortifyapp.com) that enables you to use locally enrolled certificates and smart cards with certificates and keys on them within the browser.

Alternatively, you can import a [PKCS#12 file using PKIjs](https://pkijs.org/examples/PKCS12SimpleExample.html) into the browser and then sign with that.

There is no need for Java or ActiveX for the above, just Javascript and the client if escaping the browser is necessary.